# How do I get PayPal_Express response using OmniPay?

Tags: laravel-4, omnipay, paypal

I have searched all over and have ran in circles on OmniPays github trying to find documentation on how to implement PayPal Express in OmniPay.

```
        $response = Omnipay::purchase([
            'amount' => $total,
            'encodedTestIDs' => serialize($payForTestID),
            'returnUrl' => 'http://php.bhiceu.com/payment/return',
            'cancelUrl' => 'http://php.bhiceu.com/payment/cancel' 
        ])->send();
        //dd($response);
        //die;
        if ($response->isRedirect()) {
            // redirect to offsite payment gateway
            $response->redirect();
        } else {
            // payment failed: display message to customer
            echo $response->getMessage();
        }
```

The above code successfully sends me to PayPal with the proper amount and when I cancel or check I am returned to the appropriate URLS, however all that I get back is the paypal token which I cannot find any documentation on what to do with.

Comment: Yup... Omnipay seems like it could be quite handy but the documentation is simply nonexistent. Did you ever figure out the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to complete the purchase by using completePurchase() method.

look at omnipay/example code at https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-example/blob/master/index.php#L203-L218

Answer (score 1):

The answer ended up being quite simple, but I had to go digging through the source code for it as the documentation for the library is non-existent.

```
$response = Omnipay::completePurchase([
    'amount' => $price,
    'currency' => $currency
])->send();
```

You simply call `Omnipay::completePurchase` with the same `amount` and `currency` as the initial `Omnipay::purchase` call.

After this, you would use `Omnipay::fetchCheckout()->send()` to obtain information like the shipping address etc.